# Displays to motherboard and GPU simultaneously: only mouse on the display from GPU

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-geforce

My motherboard is [GA-MA785GM-US2H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-MA785GM-US2H-rev-10#ov), I attached to it VGA and HDMI displays, it works. But I have third display and want to use it. I have old [GeForce 6600GT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_6_series). I inserted this card into slot, and found that on this display **I can see only mouse** that can change it shape according to invisible underlying content (for example "resize" cursor or "hand" cursor) while first two displays from motherboard continues to works correctly. In display manager and arandr I see all 3 displays. I tried to install Nvidia driver, but on 18.04.3 this is not in the repository, I tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt install nvidia-304` but faced with [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1763648):

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-304 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-23
              Depends: xserver-xorg-core
```

I downloaded [304 driver from official website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/123708/en-us) and tried to install it in safe mode (because I need to turn off the X server) but it was not successful:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Mon Nov 25 12:05:09 2019
installer version: 304.137

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
WARNING: Skipping the runlevel check (the utility `runlevel` failed to run).
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 304.137.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
-> Performing CC version check with CC="cc".
-> Kernel source path: '/lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build'
-> Kernel output path: '/lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build'
-> Performing rivafb check.
-> Performing nvidiafb check.
-> Performing Xen check.
-> Cleaning kernel module build directory.
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; make clean'...
-> Building kernel module:
   executing: 'cd ./kernel; make module SYSSRC=/lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build SYSOUT=/lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build'...
   NVIDIA: calling KBUILD...
   test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (     \
   echo >&2;                            \
   echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";        \
   echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
   echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";   \
   echo >&2 ;                           \
   /bin/false)
   mkdir -p /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/.tmp_versions/*
   make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel
     cc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/.nv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs 
   -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m32 -msoft-float -mregparm=3 -freg-struct-return -fno-pic -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -march=i686 -mtune=generic -Wa,-mtune=generic32 -ffreestanding -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-int-in-bool-context -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-track
   ing-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -I/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel -Wall -MD -Wsign-compare -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-error -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DNVRM -DNV_VERSION_STRING=\"304.137\" -Wno-unused-function -Wuninitialized -UDEBUG -U_DEBUG -DNDEBUG  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"nv"'  -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"nvidia"' -c -o /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.o /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c
   In file included from ./include/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:11:0,
                    from ./arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/byteorder.h:5,
                    from ./include/asm-generic/bitops/le.h:6,
                    from ./arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h:512,
                    from ./include/linux/bitops.h:18,
                    from ./include/linux/kernel.h:11,
                    from ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:45,
                    from ./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:6,
                    from ./include/linux/sched.h:12,
                    from ./include/linux/utsname.h:6,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:40,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/byteorder/generic.h: In function ‘cpu_to_be32_array’:
   ./include/linux/byteorder/generic.h:178:16: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                   ^
   ./include/linux/byteorder/generic.h: In function ‘be32_to_cpu_array’:
   ./include/linux/byteorder/generic.h:186:16: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
                   ^
   In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:5:0,
                    from ./include/linux/sched.h:12,
                    from ./include/linux/utsname.h:6,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:40,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/thread_info.h: In function ‘check_copy_size’:
   ./include/linux/thread_info.h:130:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if (unlikely(sz >= 0 && sz < bytes)) {
                                ^
   ./include/linux/compiler.h:77:42: note: in definition of macro ‘unlikely’
    # define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                             ^
   ./include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h: In function ‘queued_write_trylock’:
   ./include/asm-generic/qrwlock.h:75:36: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
              cnts, cnts | _QW_LOCKED) == cnts);
                                       ^
   ./include/linux/compiler.h:76:40: note: in definition of macro ‘likely’
    # define likely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
                                           ^
   In file included from ./include/linux/ipc.h:7:0,
                    from ./include/uapi/linux/sem.h:5,
                    from ./include/linux/sem.h:9,
                    from ./include/linux/sched.h:15,
                    from ./include/linux/utsname.h:6,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:40,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h: In function ‘rht_grow_above_75’:
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h:295:34: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     return atomic_read(&ht->nelems) > (tbl->size / 4 * 3) &&
                                     ^
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h: In function ‘rht_shrink_below_30’:
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h:308:34: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     return atomic_read(&ht->nelems) < (tbl->size * 3 / 10) &&
                                     ^
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h: In function ‘rht_grow_above_100’:
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h:320:34: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     return atomic_read(&ht->nelems) > tbl->size &&
                                     ^
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h: In function ‘rht_grow_above_max’:
   ./include/linux/rhashtable.h:332:34: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     return atomic_read(&ht->nelems) >= ht->max_elems;
                                     ^~
   In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:5:0,
                    from ./include/linux/sched.h:12,
                    from ./include/linux/utsname.h:6,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:40,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/mmzone.h: In function ‘next_zones_zonelist’:
   ./include/linux/mmzone.h:989:44: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if (likely(!nodes && zonelist_zone_idx(z) <= highest_zoneidx))
                                               ^
   ./include/linux/compiler.h:76:40: note: in definition of macro ‘likely’
    # define likely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
                                           ^
   In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/current.h:6:0,
                    from ./include/linux/sched.h:12,
                    from ./include/linux/utsname.h:6,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:40,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h: In function ‘percpu_ref_get_many’:
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:420:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define this_cpu_add_1(pcp, val) percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:379:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add_1’
      case 1: stem##1(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:511:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define this_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(this_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:177:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add’
      this_cpu_add(*percpu_count, nr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:421:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define this_cpu_add_2(pcp, val) percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:380:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add_2’
      case 2: stem##2(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:511:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define this_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(this_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:177:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add’
      this_cpu_add(*percpu_count, nr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:422:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define this_cpu_add_4(pcp, val) percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:381:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add_4’
      case 4: stem##4(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:511:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define this_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(this_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:177:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add’
      this_cpu_add(*percpu_count, nr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h: In function ‘percpu_ref_put_many’:
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:420:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define this_cpu_add_1(pcp, val) percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:379:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add_1’
      case 1: stem##1(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:511:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define this_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(this_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:521:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add’
    #define this_cpu_sub(pcp, val)  this_cpu_add(pcp, -(typeof(pcp))(val))
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:276:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_sub’
      this_cpu_sub(*percpu_count, nr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:421:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define this_cpu_add_2(pcp, val) percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:380:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add_2’
      case 2: stem##2(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:511:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define this_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(this_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:521:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add’
    #define this_cpu_sub(pcp, val)  this_cpu_add(pcp, -(typeof(pcp))(val))
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:276:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_sub’
      this_cpu_sub(*percpu_count, nr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:422:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define this_cpu_add_4(pcp, val) percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:381:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add_4’
      case 4: stem##4(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:511:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define this_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(this_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:521:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_add’
    #define this_cpu_sub(pcp, val)  this_cpu_add(pcp, -(typeof(pcp))(val))
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-refcount.h:276:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_sub’
      this_cpu_sub(*percpu_count, nr);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h: In function ‘percpu_up_read_preempt_enable’:
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:401:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define raw_cpu_add_1(pcp, val)  percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:379:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_add_1’
      case 1: stem##1(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:424:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define raw_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(raw_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:460:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_add’
     raw_cpu_add(pcp, val);      \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:498:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_add’
    #define __this_cpu_sub(pcp, val) __this_cpu_add(pcp, -(typeof(pcp))(val))
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:500:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_sub’
    #define __this_cpu_dec(pcp)  __this_cpu_sub(pcp, 1)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:97:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_dec’
      __this_cpu_dec(*sem->read_count);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:402:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define raw_cpu_add_2(pcp, val)  percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:380:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_add_2’
      case 2: stem##2(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:424:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define raw_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(raw_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:460:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_add’
     raw_cpu_add(pcp, val);      \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:498:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_add’
    #define __this_cpu_sub(pcp, val) __this_cpu_add(pcp, -(typeof(pcp))(val))
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:500:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_sub’
    #define __this_cpu_dec(pcp)  __this_cpu_sub(pcp, 1)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:97:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_dec’
      __this_cpu_dec(*sem->read_count);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:131:31: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
             ((val) == 1 || (val) == -1)) ?  \
                                  ^
   ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:403:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘percpu_add_op’
    #define raw_cpu_add_4(pcp, val)  percpu_add_op((pcp), val)
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:381:11: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_add_4’
      case 4: stem##4(variable, __VA_ARGS__);break;  \
              ^~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:424:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call’
    #define raw_cpu_add(pcp, val)  __pcpu_size_call(raw_cpu_add_, pcp, val)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:460:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘raw_cpu_add’
     raw_cpu_add(pcp, val);      \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:498:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_add’
    #define __this_cpu_sub(pcp, val) __this_cpu_add(pcp, -(typeof(pcp))(val))
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:500:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_sub’
    #define __this_cpu_dec(pcp)  __this_cpu_sub(pcp, 1)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/percpu-rwsem.h:97:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘__this_cpu_dec’
      __this_cpu_dec(*sem->read_count);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt.h:17:0,
                    from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:72,
                    from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                    from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                    from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                    from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                    from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                    from ./include/linux/utsname.h:6,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:40,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/vmstat.h: In function ‘zone_page_state_snapshot’:
   ./include/linux/cpumask.h:231:9: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
      (cpu) < nr_cpu_ids;)
            ^
   ./include/linux/cpumask.h:766:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘for_each_cpu’
    #define for_each_online_cpu(cpu)   for_each_cpu((cpu), cpu_online_mask)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/vmstat.h:210:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘for_each_online_cpu’
     for_each_online_cpu(cpu)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/vmstat.h: In function ‘node_page_state_snapshot’:
   ./include/linux/cpumask.h:231:9: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
      (cpu) < nr_cpu_ids;)
            ^
   ./include/linux/cpumask.h:766:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘for_each_cpu’
    #define for_each_online_cpu(cpu)   for_each_cpu((cpu), cpu_online_mask)
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
   ./include/linux/vmstat.h:226:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘for_each_online_cpu’
     for_each_online_cpu(cpu)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   In file included from ./include/linux/efi.h:20:0,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv-linux.h:193,
                    from /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:13:
   ./include/linux/rtc.h: In function ‘rtc_tv_nsec_ok’:
   ./include/linux/rtc.h:253:22: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if (to_set->tv_nsec < TIME_SET_NSEC_FUZZ) {
                         ^
   ./include/linux/rtc.h:258:22: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if (to_set->tv_nsec > NSEC_PER_SEC - TIME_SET_NSEC_FUZZ) {
                         ^
   /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c: In function ‘nv_start_rc_timer’:
   /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:3032:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘init_timer’; did you mean ‘init_timers’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
        init_timer(&nvl->rc_timer);
        ^~~~~~~~~~
        init_timers
   /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:3033:28: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
        nvl->rc_timer.function = nv_kern_rc_timer;
                               ^
   /tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.c:3034:18: error: ‘struct timer_list’ has no member named ‘data’
        nvl->rc_timer.data = (unsigned long) nv;
                     ^
   cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
   scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.o' failed
   make[3]: *** [/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel/nv.o] Error 1
   Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel' failed
   make[2]: *** [_module_/tmp/selfgz691/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.137/kernel] Error 2
   NVIDIA: left KBUILD.
   nvidia.ko failed to build!
   Makefile:261: recipe for target 'module' failed
   make[1]: *** [module] Error 1
   makefile:59: recipe for target 'module' failed
   make: *** [module] Error 2
-> Error.
ERROR: Unable to build the NVIDIA kernel module.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

Xubuntu 18.04.3 i386.

What can I try next? This is necessary to install Nvidia driver for using third display from GPU if it works when first two displays is not attached to motherboard?

Comment: Nvidia dropped supported for the legacy `nvidia-304` driver sometime in 2017. The new legacy driver in 18.04 is `nvidia-340`, and it wouldn't work with old cards.

Comment: I would recommend to run clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It has necessary Nvidia [304 driver version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nvidia-304). I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS on Nvidia 9600GT and 425M without problems :)

Comment: @N0rbert thank you, but my current system is five years old without reinstalling (even cloned by Clonezilla from one PC to another), for me easier option will be to sell this old GPU and by another one, with passive cooling against noise.